# Unordered integer partitions (compositions)

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How is the number of unordered integer partitions of an integer $n$ to $r$ partitions equal to $\binom{n-1+r}{r}$?

Comment: Read [Wikipedia on stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for a nice discussion.  You can search this site for the phrase for many examples.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You also have to show how you have tried to solve it.